# Install Postgresql / Postgis with SFCGAL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-database, sfcgal, postgis-2.2

I need to access ST_StraightSkeleton() function. At the moment i have a Postgresql
instalation PostgreSQL 9.3.4 compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit installed via EDB with Postgis 2.1.7 on a windows machine that seems not have SFCGAL installed.

> 1st What would be my chances of having SFCGAL installed on this installation ?
>
> 2nd I'm willing to make a fresh install of another PostgreSQL / Postgis installation  (built-in with SFGCAL) if that is less effort, but im a bit confuse on which installations and the order of installation for the .exe files at Postgis site below

http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg93/buildbot/

EDIT 1:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can wait we are planning to release 2.2.0 today. It has SFCGAL extension.

If you want to give it a try now, download the postgis 2.2.0dev windows binaries.

You'll need to use postgis 2.2. Since can't have both postgis 2.1 and 2.2 loaded in same database and postgis_sfcgal functions are in the postgis 2.2 dll.

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis VERSION "2.2.0dev";
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_sfcgal VERSION "2.2.0dev";
```

Comment: thanks , i took the risk :-) downloaded postgis-pg93-binaries-2.2.0devw64gcc48.zip unzipped and copied to my postgres folder installation overwriting all files there . Uninstalled old postgis extension from all my db's . Now when trying to install the postgis 2.2.0dev it fails with the error at EDIT 1

Comment: Any idea why this could be happening ?

Comment: Just got released.  I'm building the windows binaries now and hope to have PostGIS 2.2 bundle windows installers out by next week or week after (which will also include pgRouting 2.1 and ogr_fdw).  http://postgis.net/2015/10/07/postgis-2.2.0

Comment: Jorge,  I'll check and see what could be up here.  First of all, you might want to upgrade to 9.3.9.  9.3.4 they might have changed some things.

Comment: Forgot to add,  if you want to be more up to date, use 9.4.4 instead of 9.3. My production systems all use 9.4 currently, so I tend to test that more than the older versions (which I only test at release time). and as soon as 9.5 EDB binaries are out, I'll be building binaries for 9.5

Comment: Guess you got it working since you submitted a ticket.  How did you resolve it?

Comment: Between a few changes on my workflow like - Installation of 9.3.9 via EDB , install location in the default one pointed by EDB \Program Files ... and copy of binaries from postgis-pg93-binaries-2.2.0w64gcc48 to Postgres\whatever folder using Total Commander to sync folders , it did the trick ... now the bug ... next  fix the code, and pull to trunk :-)